# Проверка qiwi платежа по комментарию?

Tags: qiwi

Замечал на некоторых сайтах прием платежей производится не через кивишоп, а так что человек вставляет комментарий или номер транзакции, после нажатия кнопки платеж проверяется 1-2 секунды. Кто нибудь скажет как это работает?

Comment: Или через API - если дает возможность в полной мере - или бота написать ^^ Только с ботом рано или поздно будет "оплатил-где мой товар-кидалы-мать вашу???!!!" сайт же меняется...

Answer (score 1):

Вот [здесь](https://api.qiwi.com/support/check.action) инструкция по проверке платежа совершенного через терминал. После заполнения полей для ввода сервер генерирует вот такую строку - `get-запрос`.

```
https://api.qiwi.com/support/check/result.action?terminal=8888888&stringDate=01.12.2017&phone=9161234567&code=275434565
```

Здесь перечислены все введенные значения.

Данную строку запроса сгенерировать вы можете и в своем приложении. Получить и обработать ответ соответственно.

Comment: я имел ввиду другое. через терминал - то понятно. Например по комментарию к платежу.